# Load unsafe script in chrome only on a specific site

Tags: google-chrome

I have a site url that I'd like to enable unsafe scripts on, without using the --allow-running-insecure-content switch globally enabling unsafe scripts everywhere. Lets say the script is on google.com. I'd like to make it so you don't have to click the shield in the url bar and click 'load unsafe script'. I'd like to enable this via url only, as to not allow unsafe scripts globally. Any ideas?

Comment: What about accessing that site over http? If you're going to load unsafe scripts on that site, then https doesn't guarantee privacy/security any more.

Comment: The problem is that the site forces http. For example try typing these urls with http:// in front http://google.com or http://facebook.com

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more context? E.g. are either of the sites yours? Are the untrusted sites also available over https? Are the scripts (location, content) static?

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously not recommended, but you can go ahead and add the sites to your allowed list in content settings.

Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Content Settings > Javascript > Manage Exceptions

Afterwards make sure to clear your cache/cookies, etc...

Comment: This setting does not seem to be available in Chrome any more.